# Remote Desktop Connection Manager (RDCman) does not go full screen anymore

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm using the Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7 on a Surface Pro 4 with Windows 10. Until recently, it was working fine: It would go to full screen and show this blue full screen connection bar at the top when pointing there with the mouse. I could close the session from there or leave full screen mode.

A few days ago (no idea what happened), it stopped going to full screen properly. Now it only resizes to the full size of my screen minus the task bar (so I still see that and the RDCman's window is also not behind my local task bar. The blue bar at the top appears for a moment but I cannot get it back when moving the mouse there.

Reinstalling did not help. Any idea what might have caused this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Simpler - just don't maximize the Remote Desktop Connection Manager window.

I just resize the RDCMan window to "almost" maximum size, then hit Full Screen in the RemoteDesktop connection (right click-> Full Screen).

Otherwise, it seems Windows 10 keeps a bottom bar reserved for the taskbar & doesn't allow the remote desktop to go "all the way" Fullscreen.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Really nonsense behavior of Windows...

Comment: I don't want to +1 this, but this has been nagging at me for 3 years of using a High DPI and this totally worked.  Bookmarking this!

Comment: +1 for this solution, simple and easiest to full screen with high DPI device, no need to play with registry hack, however, is there any way to hide the remote desktop connection bar in Remote Desktop Connection Manager?

Comment: Wow. Didn't understand what you meant at first. Basically if your RDCMan is maximized, your screwed and it won't hide your status bar. If you have it not maximized, full screen works as expected. Weird.

Comment: This also fixes the issue with key combinations (like Alt+Tab/Windows key) not being forwarded to the remote you are connecting to. Super strange behavior...

Comment: @Bilo just go to View > Options > Full-screen > uncheck "show connection full-screen connection bar"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I had a similar problem and found that this worked:

1. Find `rcdman.exe`.
   Default location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Remote Desktop Connection Manager\RDCMan.exe`
2. Open the `Properties` of the exe (`Right click -> Properties`)
3. Go to the `Compatibility` tab
4. Uncheck `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings`

Answer (score 2):

Click View, then un-check Lock window size.

Comment: Thanks, but it was already unchecked.

Comment: Is the remote desktop size still set to Full screen? Either at this specific connection entry, or the parent folder, or however you have it setup.

Comment: Yes, and the size of the remote desktop is also the size of my local screen (I just get scrollbars instead of expanding properly over the task bar).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps and settings to make RDCM fit full screen, even over the taskbar, in Windows 10.

1. Right click the server connection > Properties.
2. Display settings tab > Check "Scale docked..." and "Scale undocked..." (I actually just tested and these are not needed for full screen, but I recommend them anyway - I despise the scrollbars).
3. Remote Desktop Settings tab > Check "Inherit from Parent" (This might be variable, start with this to see)
4. Make sure RDCM window is NOT maximized. This is very important otherwise the RDC window will not go full screen when you do the next step (it would still be hidden behind the taskbar and it will have scroll bars, we don't want that). It can be any size window you want, just not maximized.
5. Either of these:

- Right click your server and select "Full Screen"

or

- Press CTRL+ALT+PAUSE/BREAK (pressing this again will shrink out of full screen as well.

Your RDC should now be taking up the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfnetwork/surface-pro-4-windows-10-remote-desktop-other/d17d4321-0f04-4a64-95b4-1c6dd5de9c91?page=1

> Here is what I did to solve the issue.  It also works with older apps that don't handle high dpi scaling well. First one must tell Windows to look for a manifest file for an application by default – a registry entry. Next is to provide a manifest file for a given application – the executable file name followed by `.manifest`.

1. Open RegEdit and navigate to the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > SideBySide.
2. Right-click, select NEW > DWORD (32 bit) value.
3. Type `PreferExternalManifest`, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click `PreferExternalManifest`, and then click Modify.
5. Enter Value Data 1 and select Decimal.
6. Click OK. Exit Registry Editor.
7. The RDP app is `%windir%\System32\mstsc.exe` so the manifest file is mstsc.exe.manifest.

> I can't attach the manifest file so here is the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity 
                type="win32"
                name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
                publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
                language="*">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                type="win32"
                name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
                version="9.0.21022.8"
                processorArchitecture="amd64"
                publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel
                    level="asInvoker"
                    uiAccess="false"/>
                </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
           <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            false
            </ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

> Copy the above into notepad and save the file with the appropriate name to the same folder as the executable.

Comment: This is the solution to a different problem...

Comment: Thought it would help. Do you have to use RDCMan? [Royal TS](https://www.royalapplications.com/ts/win/features) is a pretty good application.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the host, properties>display settings: uncheck inherit from parent and check scale docked remote desktop to fit window

On v2.7 build 1406.0, not sure if this was released in an update, just wanted to point it out in case people are still searching.